# How to extract date in excel spreadsheet using LEFT and RIGHT function?

Tags: excel

The date is in following format-
" yyyy/mm/dd hr/min/sec " I want to separate date and time in two different columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the data stored with said format or is it a string formatted like that? If it's in that format, you might use functions like HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, YEAR, MONTH and DAY. If it's a string, you might use functions like LEFT, RIGHT, MID, FIND.

Comment: Use `INT()` for the Dates while `MOD()` for the Times.

Answer (score 0):

for year: LEFT(A1,4)
for mm: MID(A1,6,2)
for dd: MID(A1,9,2)
for hr: MID(A1,12,2)
for mm: MID(A1,15,2)
for ss: RIGTH(A1,2)

Answer (score 0):

If It is string, Then look for the space character to take them apart: like this:

Date Part:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

Time Part:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

Then you can format your columns to adapt to your settings:

[image: FGDDSDGFHHHHHH]